# Can a miswired UTP cable destroy a router?

Tags: networking, router

So we had this cheap [TP-Link](http://www.tp-link.com.au/products/details/TL-WR740N.html) router for a couple of years, only using LAN1 port and wi-fi. We now have another pc requiring direct connection; for the first few weeks I just plugged it in LAN2, but the cable was going through everything, so I decided I want the router in another room.

The setting is an apartment house, so I assume there is a main device somewhere in the basement, the apartment just gets a UTP. That cable went through a hole in the doorframe to the original room the router was in, so I had to cut it, and reassemble (I bought RJ45 plugs and a crimping tool).

When I plugged the whole thing back together, at first the internet light didn't light up. I tried resetting the router and some other stuff randomly until I noticed that I wired the whole thing upside down - "straight" UTP color codes but I held the RJ45 with the little pin facing up.

So I cut it and did it properly, even checked how it was before the original cut (btw. I noticed that brown-white and brown was switched there, not sure if that matters, it worked for years). When reassembled the internet light lit up but to my surprise, the LAN1 light also did, without anything even plugged in.

Since then I tried everything, starting from LAN2, resetting the router, even a wireless firmware upgrade, only wireless works through the router, nothing through any kind of cables (tried 2 computers, 3 cables). LAN1 continues to be lit regardless of what is plugged where.

I can access wi-fi without a problem, even log in to the router. Also if I plug the WAN cable directly into a PC, it works after I set up the PPPoE connection.

Could it be that my mistake with the wiring somehow permanently damaged the router?

Comment: No. There isn't any high voltage going through a LAN.

Comment: @LPChip I know that but why is the LAN1 led still going insane after multiple resets and a firmware upgrade?

Comment: LPChip: should that not  be the answer?

Comment: The voltage doesn't have to be _high_ to fry some things, but ... I think that's why Ethernet ports have the magnetic coupling?

Comment: Can just incorrect wiring damage a port? Yes, it can... but it is not likely, it would take an unusual set of circumstances for that to occur, so rare I can't describe them off the top of my head. Still, we are talking about electronics here, a simple static shock from walking across the carpet can destroy a switch port or even the entire router. This could even happen if you had one end hooked to the router and were terminating the other end on the other side of the house and had a static discharge. Not to mention, electronics can just fail. The point is the router is bad, replace it.