# Can a miswired ethernet cable destroy a client when connected to a POE switch?

Tags: ethernet, wiring

This question is similar to [Can a miswired UTP cable destroy a router?](https://superuser.com/questions/1172920/can-a-miswired-utp-cable-destroy-a-router) - except my circumstances are more specific.

I have a client (A solax Hybrid inverter), where the installer wired the ethernet connection incorrectly - specifically he used 568B wiring, but he reversed the connector, so pin 1 went to pin 8, 2 to 7 and so on.   Not knowing this, I then attempted to wire the other side of the cable (I tried both 568A and 568B wiring), and plugged it into my POE switch.

I've now corrected the wiring issue on the inverter side, but I am not getting any connectivity to the switch.   Unfortunately the inverter is still not connecting to ethernet, and I'm wondering if the port could have been damaged by the incorrect cabling?

Comment: "I tried both..." - Might I suggest a ethernet tester?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek the initial problem I had was that I only had access to 1 side of the cable.  (The other was behind a panel with mains and higher voltages which I was loathe to go near).  In the end, after being wrongly assured it was safe to do so, I opened the panel and corrected the ethernet wiring.

Comment: I think this depends on whether you're asking about standard 802.1af PoE (negotiated between devices) or 'passive' PoE (blasting 24V without much care).

Answer (score 0):

The answer would appear to be no (at least in this case, and I suspect most standard cases).   I fixed the problem issue and the port came to life.

Thinking about it, this makes sense as POE has negotiation (at least of 802.1af and newer) of power - so this negotiation would presumably fail before power blew anything up.

Comment: " I fixed the problem issue" what did you do to fix it? That should be in the answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill I'm not actually sure what the problem issue was.  After the cable and testing it with my cable tester it started working.   I'm not sure its relevant to my question though (ie could wrong ethernet wiring, combined with POE blow up a port)